# Compare 1 parameter to multiple fields in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to do something like this in my query:

```
 $query = $mysqldb->make_query("SELECT * FROM dvd WHERE
 NAME LIKE '%{$str_param}%' OR
 CATEGORY={$str_param} OR
 TYPE={$str_param} OR BOOK={$str_param} OR 
 PAGE={$str_param}");
```

Where I will only use 1 parameter, and it will be compared to any of the fields. But I get this warning:

```
mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your query so `make_query` returns a `FALSE` instead of a `resource`.

Since `str_param` usually assumes a string, you should enclose it into single quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM dvd WHERE
 NAME LIKE '%{$str_param}%' OR
 CATEGORY='{$str_param}' OR
 TYPE='{$str_param}' OR BOOK='{$str_param}' OR 
 PAGE='{$str_param}'
```

Make sure you use `mysql_real_escape_string` on any user-provided data to avoid `SQL` injection.